# Can I cut other computer connection from terminal or software?

Tags: networking, connection

I have a modem that can be accessed with my brother. Sometimes my brother plays internet games and it makes my connection slower.

Can I cut my brother internet connection via terminal? If not, which packages / software I should use if there isn't any facilities for cutting the connection.

Comment: are you talking about router? Oh what means _" can be accessed with my brother"_?

Comment: Sorry, I mean cut other computer connection

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indeed you can.

To do this, we use a command line utility (which should be already installed) for network manager called `nmcli`.

## To disconnect

you need to run the following command:

```
nmcli dev disconnect iface eth0
```

**Note:** You need to make sure that the iface value for the connection is `eth0`, you can do so by taking a look at the status of all the devices:

```
nmcli dev status
```

[image: nmcli dev status output]

Note that, in this case, `eth0` is connected, hence the iface value is `eth0`.

## To connect again

you need to know the `uuid` of the connection. Run the following command:

```
nmcli con
```

and note the `uuid` of your connection.

Then, to connect to that connection, run

```
nmcli con up uuid <uuid>
```

where `<uuid>` is the uuid you noted from the previous command.